# How do I combine two lists of strings into one list of strings?

Tags: haskell

How do I combine two lists of strings into one list of strings?

For example, this:

```
["aaaaaa", "aaaaaa","aaaaaa"] 
["bbbb", "bbbb", "  bb"]
```

would go into this:

```
["aaaaaabbbb","aaaaaabbbb", "aaaaaa  bb"]
```

Comment: what did you try? do you know hoogle? HINT: the function you are looking for works like a `zip`per `With` concatenation of lists.

Comment: Thank you so much!! looks like the zipWith (++) function works my question!

Answer (score 5):

```
zipWith (++) ["aaaaaa", "aaaaaa","aaaaaa"] ["bbbb", "bbbb", " bb"]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `zipWith`:

```
concatStrings :: [String] -> [String] -> [String]
concatStrings = zipWith (++)
```